# Installed Office 2007 in Wine, How to Run Them?

Tags: wine, microsoft-office

I installed Office 2007 using Wine1.6 on Ubuntu 14.04. Seemed to go fine but I can't find the Office executables to get them to run. I would also like to add the shortcuts to the toolbar or desktop

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Office 2007 typically installs to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office` on Windows 64-bit.  We can kind of assume that this will apply in the case of Wine as well, but we need to change `C:\` to a Linux file path.

The default wine prefix, and the `drive_c` directory, ends up in your user profile data, such that wine's `C:` drive is in `/home/$USER/.wine/drive_c`.

Try searching in `/home/$USER/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office` as a starting point.  Keep in mind that you should probably put that entire string in single quotes, like so:  `cd '/home/$USER/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office'`

Within that directory, you should find some kind of `OFFICE##` directory in there.  If I remember correctly, Office 2007 is `OFFICE12`.  The binaries should be within that folder (`/home/$USER/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/OFFICE12/`).  You will need to know the actual executable names to run with the `wine` command, or you can double click the `.exe` (`winword.exe` for example is Word).

Comment: I do not comment on adding the shortcuts to them because I do not know the logical way to reliably add shortcuts or methods to execute them.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to install MSO on Linux is with [PlayOnLinux](https://www.playonlinux.com/). You just choose Microsoft Office from a list, point it to the installer file, and then click through the installer using default values. After that, shortcuts will be installed for Word,  Excel etc.

Comment: Thank you my friend. Worked perfectly. Only hiccup was working out that I needed to mount the disc image from my external HDD.